# Change multiple attr of a div with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap progress bar that is getting its data by a js function

**Here is the progress bar**

```
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%" id="progress">40%</div>
```

**And here is the js to update the bar**

```
function refreshProgress(){
        $('#progress').load('progress.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTableData, 5000);
        });
```

**The problem I have**

The js updates only the content of the div but can't figure out how to update also the values of
`aria-valuenow="40"` and `style="width:40%"`

**I was thinking of something like**

```
$("#progress").attr({
      "aria-valuenow" : "the progress.php value",
      "style" : "the progress.php value"
    });
```

But not sure how to do it, if that is the way that it can be done.

**UPDATE**

What I am aiming for is aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%" as well as the div content to update in the same time with one call to progress.php

Comment: Just a note, about the `style` attribute, you can use [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) to change it

Comment: From what I can see this should work, so I don't see any problem in code you posted.

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried what you thought?

Comment: You should try what you wrote in your question before asking, because it works exactly like you did :)

Comment: I just had this idea while researching possible solutions. The problem is that I am not good with js and not sure how to merge the two pieces.

Comment: That is another question then

Comment: @vincent-d so you are saying that after running it in the way I wrote it, it will update all pieces "aria-valuenow", "style" and the div contents? Dont thnk so!

Comment: I don't know what your php contains, I don't know why it is not an xhr call, I don't know why you don't pull a .html() or .text() to change the 40% text. All I can tell that is the answer to the question 'Change multiple attr of a div with JS' Is in your own post :\ Oh, and It's not me who downvoted your post (in case you were wondering)

Comment: The php returns a simple value like a number "40", nothing more. I am not concerned about the downvote at all :) But good to know

Comment: check my answer mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the way you try to update your attr is the good one.

```
$("#progress").attr({
  "aria-valuenow" : "the progress.php value",
  "style" : "the progress.php value"
});
```

What you want now is to put the number returned by your php in your content as well as your attribute `aria-valuenow`

A way to do it is by making an xhr call with the anwser returned by the server

```
setInterval(
$.post(
  "progress.php",
  function(resp) {
       // first I check if my answer is 100 so I stop the interval
       if(resp === '100') {return false}
       //if not, I update my bar
       $("#progress").attr("aria-valuenow",resp).css('width',resp+'%').empty().text(resp+"%");
  }
),
5000);
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was aiming to do! Of course, I would have had just update the whole div in the progress.php file and then print it all together in another div, but that would not be nice at least from a performance point of view. Your solution is just perfect. Thanks!

Comment: it depends how your page is made and the ressources needed, because the solution you are talking about is better if you need to have a perfect control over the bar status. In my solution, if the client have a lag and miss a paquet, the resp may never be equal to 100 (in certain case, again I don't know about your progress.php :) )
Glad to help, enjoy

Comment: Absolutely it helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`.attr` will take an object as you are currently using. This is a little demo showing that:

```js
let value = 0;
const updateProgress = (value) => {
  const pb = $('#progress');
  value = value + 10;
  pb.attr({
    "aria-valuenow": value,
    "style": 'width:' + value + '%'
  }).text(value + '%');
  if (value <= 90) {
    setTimeout(updateProgress, 1000, value);
  }
}

updateProgress(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="progress" style="height:10px; width:90%; margin: 10px auto; height: 20px">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%" id="progress">40%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.attr` will accept an object as you are suggesting: https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes

> #### Setting several attributes at once
>
> To change the alt attribute and add the title attribute at the same time, pass both sets of names and values into the method at once using a plain JavaScript object. Each key-value pair in the object adds or modifies an attribute:
>
> ```
> $("#greatphoto").attr({
>   alt: "Beijing Brush Seller",
>   title: "photo by Kelly Clark"
> });
> ```

What you could also do if jQuery wouldn't support that:

```
const update = {
  "aria-valuenow" : "the progress.php value",
  "style" : "the progress.php value"
}
for (const prop in update) {
  $("#progress").attr(prop, update[prop]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to define an additional constant, you can also go with an inline object literal:

```
for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries({
    "aria-valuenow" : "the progress.php value",
    "style" : "the progress.php value"
  })
) {
  $("#progress").attr(prop, value);
}
```

Something along these lines will be what jQuery does internally anyway.

Comment: I don't think that attr can't accept obj https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes

Comment: @CarlBinalla Thanks for pointing out, adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @vincent-d I just posted an update about what I am aiming to do. All the updates should happen at the same time, so... no there is no answer in the initial question I have posted.